# Changes to object from directive does not propagate to parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a sort of "roll back" feature. Here's what I've got:

Starting with a pretty simple object:

```
var allMetals = [
    {name: "Gold", rating: 9},
    {name: "Silver", rating: 8},
    {name: "Copper", rating: 7}];
```

And they can be edited. I've got a directive that handles the edit. The displayed list is something like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="m in allMetals">
        {{m.name}} 
        <span>{{m.rating}}</span>
        <a href="" ng-click="edit(m.name)"</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the repeater markup:

```
<div edit-metal="" metal="currentMetal" ng-show="editing"></div>
```

In the edit function, I'm just setting the value for `currentMetal` setting a flag so the edit directive becomes visible.

```
function edit(name) {
    $scope.currentMetal = helper.getMetalByName(name);
    $scope.editing = true;
}
```

Now, in the directive, I have a simple text box that's bound to the model and when user edits, I can see the parent scope var being updated and everything is dandy.
But sometimes, after editing, I might change my mind and decide to cancel the changes. So I've got a cancel function that does just this.

```
// in the directive link()
var uneditedMetal = _.clone($scope.metal); 

$scope.cancel = function(){
    $scope.metal = uneditedMetal;       
}

$scope.save = () {
    //do nothing as parent handles save with a different user button
}
```

Now, for this to work, I have to update the directive's `currentMetal` value every time the user clicks on 'edit', so I can make a backup of it before it's edited; in case cancel button is clicked. I tried to do it with `$scope.$watch('metal', function(){ /*clone here*/ })` but it seemed to be triggered too many times, so now I'm broadcasting on the parent's `edit()` function and using a `$scope.$on()` to copy a backup of the value.

I am not sure this is the best way to achieve this, if you have suggestions please let me know.

My problem, though, is that when `cancel()` is invoked, I know the value being set is the right value, and it changes the value in directive, but it doesn't propogate to the parent scope!
Even bizarrely, instead of using `$scope.metal = uneditedMetal` to copy, if I just did `$scope.metal.name = "Mercury"`, that change gets propogated, but neither object assignment nor another `_.clone()` works. I don't quite understand where the changes are being lost. Any ideas?

Here's a plnkr that reproduces my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/VKLr8gMVLyYkNvJJOGKa?p=preview

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

---

*steps to reproduce problem* :

1. Edit any item in the list
2. Modify any value in textboxes (and watch the parent list change)
3. Click cancel.

I want the parent changes to be reverted when I click cancel, but it isn't happening.

Comment: Not clear what problem is. What steps in demo reproduce it?

Comment: @charlietfl added steps to reproduce

Comment: try `angular.extend($scope.metal , currentMetal);` instead of `$scope.metal = currentMetal` ...process seems backwards, edit clone and only update live model on save

Comment: basically you are breaking the object reference passed to the directive scope

Comment: Hi, sorry, if the referene is broken, why does it get updated when I edit? I tried doing your suggested way first, but it wouldn't copy the edited object to parent object, so I reverted it, now I can edit, just cannot revert. Also, `angular.extend` didn't do anything..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/yjjpCFHdLcV4xbLmAdXM?p=preview

Comment: Blimey, that works @charlietfl, thank you. I put the `angular.extend` in parent instead of directive.. Can you post your comment as answer please?

Comment: @charlietfl - Hi, I'm still waiting for your comment to be made into answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 0):

I've written inline edit directive, which does the same thing as you are doing, edit and cancel edit functionalities. 
You can use this directive as:

```html
<inline-edit 
  ng-model="yourmodel" 
  input-type="'text'" 
  label="your label'"
  label-width="3"
  input-width="9"             
  isdisabled="true">
</inline-edit>
```

```js
angular.module('common.inlineEdit', [])

.directive('inlineEdit', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout ) {
  return {
      require: "ngModel",
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
          updateFn: '&',
          isdisabled: '=',
          inputType: '=',
          label: '=',
          labelWidth: '=',
          inputWidth: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "directives/inlineEdit/inlineEdit.tpl.html",
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.model = {};
        var cancelEditTimer;
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          scope.model.value = ngModel.$viewValue;
        };
        scope.cancelEdit = function () {
          cancelEditTimer = $timeout(function(){
                              scope.model.value = ngModel.$viewValue;
                              scope.editing = false;
                            },300);
        };
        scope.saveEdit = function () {
          scope.editing = false;
          scope.updateFn({value: scope.model.value});
        };
        scope.edit = function () {
          scope.editing=true;
                  $timeout(function(){
                      scope.input = (elm[0].querySelector('input[type="text"]'));
                    scope.input.focus();
                  },100);       
        };
        scope.select = function () {
                  $timeout(function(){
                    scope.editing=true;
                    $timeout.cancel(cancelEditTimer);
                  },10); 
        };
      }
  };
}]);
```

And the template file for directive is :

```html
<div ng-mouseover="showEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="showEdit = false" class="row inline-edit">
 <div class="col-sm-{{labelWidth}}">
  <b>{{label}} </b>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-{{inputWidth}}">
  <span ng-show="!editing">{{model.value}} </span>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o edit" ng-show="!isdisabled && showEdit && !editing" ng-click="edit()"></a>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8" ng-if="editing && inputType=='text'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.value" class="form-control input-sm" ng-blur="cancelEdit()">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 action-buttons"> 
    <a class="fa fa-check save" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="saveEdit()" ng-show="editing"></a>
    <a class="fa fa-times cancel" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="cancelEdit()" ng-show="editing"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```